# Use props without component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am working a VueJS, and I want to pass a variable coming from Laravel server to VueJS.

Here is my code:

```
<div v-for="team in championships.find((elem) => elem.championship == {{ $championship->id }}).teams"
                 v-cloak
                 :championship= {{ json_encode($championship) }} >
```

It be important to me to have a Vue Object named championship, with current championship in vue, so I could loop in the teams with:

```
    <div v-for="team in championship.teams" ... >
```

But I know how to do it in a component, with `props`, but I don't know how to get the championship object in Vue without props. In `data`, I can't make it work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `<head>` tag add the "championship" property to the window object like this:

```
<script>
 window.championship = {{ $championship }};
</script>
```

Then in your Vue instance data object define "championship" to the previously defined property:

```
data: {
  championship: championship
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that, but, I feel like it is not so clean. I was doing it before, but I had the hope to be able to use `v-bind` .  It seems it is not possible, as I read the answers.

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro I do this for small variables.. but for large amounts of data you can always make an Ajax request to the Backend to get your data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be a lot easier if you make Laravel as a api server and make your application into an "SPA".

Anyway, the Vue.js template grammar could only work when you include your object into Vue's instance Which intends to be something

either

```
Vue.component('someComponent',{
  template: `<h1>Hello</h1>`
})
```

or

```
<template>
   <h1>Hello</h1>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'hello',
    ...
  }
</script>
```

So, directly writing your template into Vue style would not make it work.
But, you may still pass the `$championship` to front as a javascript variable and use vue.js to render the data.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    var championComponent = Vue.component({
      template: `
        <div v-for="team in championship.teams">
          <span>{{ team }}</span>
        </div>
      `,
      data: function () {
        return {
          championship: {{ json_encode($championship) }} // parse your champion data here
        }
      }
    });
    var app = new Vue({
      el: "#app"
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Good luck!

Comment: mmm. lot easier, I don't know, but a lot of work, yes. I would have to migrate all authentication, roles, translations, routes, etc... It would be a great improvement with no doubt, but it is a lot of work, so easy is not the right word maybe :)

Comment: I think I am quite clear about how to pass your $championship variable to front. And there is no way writing your html tags in Vue style directly into your template files.